# Правильный запрос к JSON-объекту

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Имеется JSON-объект. В этот объект вложен вложен массив(*вторая модель*).
Для каждого такого вложения, создавал класс в пакете моделей, получилось нечто подобное:

*Первая модель*

```
public class Form {

    @SerializedName("groups")
    List<Groupss> mGroupss;

    public List<Groupss> getmGroupss() {
        return mGroupss;
}
```

*Вторая модель*

```
public class Groupss {

    @SerializedName("2")
    List<First> mFirst;

    public List<First> getmFirst() {
        return mFirst;
}
```

*Третья модель*

```
public class First {

    @SerializedName("type")
    String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
}
```

Прописал запрос к *getTitle* в *MainActivity*(использую retrofit).

```
public void onResponse(Call<DropDown> call, Response<DropDown> response) {
            DropDown jsonResponse = response.body();
            Log.d("type",jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss().get(1).getmControls().get(2).getTitle()+"");
```

А что делать если у меня как минимум два JSON-объекта к которым необходимо обращаться?

Comment: `jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss().get(<тут индекс элемента в массиве>).getmFirst().get(<тут индекс элемента в массиве>).getTitle();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как решил данную задачу:

Так как у нас два JSON-объекта, которые нам придётся получать, а на пути к ним у нас "пролегает" List(а второй JSON-объект также String).

Делаем следующие действия:

1) Добавляем в MainActivity

```
private List<Groupss> mList =new ArrayList<>();
```

2) Далее объявляем:

```
adapter = new DataAdapter(mList);
```

3) Корректируем метод onResponse:

```
public void onResponse(Call<DropDown> call, Response<DropDown> response) {
            DropDown jsonResponse = response.body();
            mList.addAll(jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("type",jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss().get(1).getmControls().get(2).getTitle()+" drop");
```

4) После чего подстраиваем под себя наш adapter. Лично я использовал в приложении два ViewHolder'a. Если коротко о нём, то код получился примерно такой:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public static final int TYPE_TEXTVIEW = 0;
public static final int TYPE_EDITVIEW = 1;
private List<Groupss> mList;

public DataAdapter(List<Groupss> list) {
    this.mList = list;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.text_numeric, parent, false);
            return new NumericViewHolder(view);
        case 1:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drop_down_options, parent, false);
            return new DropDownViewHolder(view);
        default:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drop_down_options, parent, false);
            return new DropDownViewHolder(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Groupss grup = mList.get(position);
    final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);

        switch (itemType){
            case TYPE_TEXTVIEW:
                ((NumericViewHolder) holder).title.setText(String.valueOf(grup.getmControls().get(0).getTitle()));
                break;
            case TYPE_EDITVIEW:
                ((DropDownViewHolder) holder).title_options.setText(String.valueOf(grup.getmControls().get(0).getTitle()));
                break;
            default:
                ((DropDownViewHolder) holder).title_options.setText("Not found");
                break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mList == null)
        return 0;
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int temp= -1;
    if (mList.get(position).getmControls().size()>0)
    switch (mList.get(position).getmControls().get(0).getTitle()){
        case "textbox_numeric":
            temp=0;
            break;
        case "drop_down_options":
            temp = 1;
            break;
        default:
            temp =1;
    }
    return temp;
}

public class NumericViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private  TextView title;

    public NumericViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}

public class DropDownViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private EditText title_options;

    public DropDownViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title_options = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_options);
    }
}
```

Как то так)

Answer (score 0):

Это делается через цикл for. Нужно пробежаться по элементам массива и выбрать нужное вам значение.

Comment: Дело в том что все полученные значения буду выводить в recyclerView
поэтому такой вариант наверное не совсем подходит.
Поправьте меня, если ошибаюсь и лучше наглядно, т.к. я еще многих приёмов не знаю.

Comment: Ответом не является, однозначно, является советом.

Comment: @RustamUmarov, Советы лучше оставлять в комментариях к вопросу.

Comment: @Elena, спасибо за полезный совет. Но что если человек хотел добавить комментарий, и случайно написал в поле для ответа?

Comment: @RustamUmarov, ну бывает)

Comment: @RustamUmarov и всё же вопрос остаётся открытым))

Comment: @VadimMorozov абсолютно верно подмеченно, апвоут Вам за это оставлю, пожалуй. Давайте, дождемся ответа вместе =)